# Modifying the sort order of a LINQ query

Tags: linq

I expected the following LINQ query to sort according to FirstName but the OrderBy extension method seems to have no effect.

```
DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();

var query = from contact in dc.Contacts
            select contact;

query.OrderBy(c => c.FirstName);
```

Everything works fine when I include the orderby in the initial query definition but I want to be able to modify it based on conditions later in my code.

Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try using

```
query = query.OrderBy(c => c.FirstName);
```

or

```
var sortedQuery = query.OrderBy(c => c.FirstName);
```

The OrderBy creates a new sequence.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that OrderBy is not modifying the existing query.  Instead it's creating a new query which orders the values in query.  You need to capture this result

```
var sortedQuery = query.OrderBy(c => c.FirstName);
```

This is true of virtually every single LINQ operator.  The do not actually modify the query in question.  Instead they filter or project the result of the query into a new query value and return it from the method.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @Mike Two's response, remember that to have multiple sorts you'll need to use ThenBy after the initial OrderBy for it to work, otherwise you'll just replace the first ordering.

```
var query = from contact in dc.Contacts
        select contact;

query = query.OrderBy(c => c.FirstName); 
query = query.ThenBy(c => c.LastName);

foreach (var contact in query)
{
  ...
}
```

Actually, my preference would be to chain them all together using extension methods, but *obviously this won't work if you need to make them conditional*.

```
var query = dc.Contacts
              .OrderBy( c => c.FirstName )
              .ThenBy( c => c.LastName );

foreach (var contact in query)
{
   ...
}
```